# Should it be "on your job" or "during your job"?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if we should say "during your job" or "on your job" if you're doing X as part of your job and not as a side thing or kill time.

For example:

> The sketch artist draw portraits on the job after hearing a
>   description of the suspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common usage is one of

> A sketch artist’s job is drawing portraits based on a verbal description of a suspect.

or

> The sketch artists draw portraits on the job …

or

> The sketch artists draw portraits at work …

The definite article reads a bit strangely if you are describing the profession as a whole, in which case

> Sketch artists draw portraits at work …

would be better. Where the definite article might make sense is if you are referring to a group of sketch artists who are part of a specific larger team.

To emphasize the purpose for which someone is employed, in contrast to responding to email, filing paperwork, attending staff meetings, and other overhead or unproductive tasks, use

> Sketch artists get paid to draw …

Slightly more formal is

> The job description for sketch artists includes drawing …

or

> A sketch artist’s primary job function (or primary duty) is drawing portraits …

Comment: So "on the job" is like "during and for the job"?

Comment: @frbsfok "On the job" does not necessarily mean it is part of your job description. "He was fired for sleeping on the job." "Thanks for the offer, but I'm on duty. Drinking on the job is not allowed." or you could be "injured on the job."